# Office 2016 Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers

Tags: ms-office, office-interop, office-2016

Office 2016 has been released, where can I get the list of the control IDs?
[Searching the microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=User%20Interface%20Control%20Identifiers) site I can only find office 2007-2013 control identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has published the help files for Office 2016. You can get it from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Comment: It was published on 1/22/2016. So, at the time the question was asked there was no control IDs.

Answer (score 2):

They were not published yet. Try to use for Office 2013 or wait until Microsoft publishes the full list of controls for Office 2016.

UPDATE: The list of [Office 2016 ribbon control IDs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745) is available for download.